# Повторяется условие if, но не выполняется следующие

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.search').click(function() {
  var ths = $(this),
    form = ths.find('#cse-search-box'),
    int = ('input[type=text]'),
    val = form.find(int).val();
  
  if(form.hide()) {
   form.show().find(int).focus();
  } else if (val.length<=1) {
   form.hide();
  } else {
   form.submit();
  };

 });
```

```css
.fa{padding:30px;background-color:red;margin-left:250px}
#cse-search-box{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <div class="search-field">
    <form action="/search.html" id="cse-search-box">
      <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-xxx:xxx" />
      <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:10" />
      <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
      <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Поиск по сайту..." />
    </form>
  </div> 
  <i class="fa fa-search" title="Поиск по сайту"></i></div>
</div>
```

Есть иконка поиска и форма, по клику на иконку должна появляться форма в который есть input. Второй клик должен определить если в input пусто, то скрывать форму, если нет то применять условие submit для формы. У меня выполняется лишь первое условие.

Выполняется лишь эта часть if(form.hide())

Comment: Вы исполняете метод hide в условии. Конечно оно всегда будет true и никогда не пойдет дальше.  Метод hide выставляет свойство display в none (поправьте, если ошибаюсь) -> Вам надо проверять "а не none ли у меня в display?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.hide()` как и `form.show()` возвращает ту же самую jQuery обертку `form`, которая в булевском смысле соответствует `true`.

```
    //if(form.hide()) { 
    if(!form.is(":visible")) {
```